# Array Ascending algorithm c++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, class

I'm having some issues with my ascending function algorithm. The function Reaches the largest element of the function and then sets it in every spot. For instance, you enter inputs in the following order: 88, 72, 81.
Then you get 88,88,88 instead of 72, 81, 88;

Code:

```
void orderGrades(Student grades[], int studentNumber){
int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

for(startScan = 0; startScan < (studentNumber - 1); startScan++){
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = grades[startScan].getGrade();
    for(int index = startScan + 1; index < studentNumber; index++)
    {
        if(grades[index].getGrade() < minValue)
            {
                grades[index].setGrade(minValue);
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        grades[minIndex].setGrade(grades[startScan].getGrade());
        grades[startScan].setGrade(minValue);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I am overlooking with the logic so I wanted to see if someone else has a different perspective.

Comment: Are you missing a `else` or `continue` after the `if` block?

Comment: To sort an array you can use the [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function to do the hard work and you can go fishing or star gazing.

Comment: @ Raw N I absolutely could, however, I'm trying to understand the algorithm for my own knowledge.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I might be. The algorithms I've mean learning from have not had either however.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Used a debugger couldn't find the issue thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you the entire solution, I can give you a hint ... After running your program in a debugger, I saw that in your if statement inside your inner for loop, you overwrite the value of the next item and it is forever lost; this will happen for every array element on the first iteration of the outer for loop (this is why you get 88 in every element). Lucky you provided a test case that failed :-)

Comment: I was able to find the solution on my own and I decided to make a completely different algorithm. Those statements were the issue so instead I kept the variable shifting in the nest for loop. Thank you by the way, i appreciate your response :)